# Moving object is not working but i have no errors

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function, object, animation

I wrote some actionscript 3 code for moving an object when another object gets close.
I use flash cs5.5
The problem is that when i added some code for moving that object only once, the code stop working properly. Maybe the problem is not code itself but something in the objects or the instances of the objects but i didn't change anything.
I am getting all the traces you can see in the code but when i close the "magnet" to the "pendulum" the pendulum is not moving-rotating as it did.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

var angle:Number = 0; //angle for rotation of object "pendulum"
var rotate:Number = 45; // value to multiple to calculate rotation

//global variable
var moved_once: int=0; //variable for checking the first move of the object 

function move_pendulum(e:Event):void{

    trace("hit"); //to check if enters the function
 pendulum1.rotation = Math.sin(angle) * rotate; //execute rotation
 angle +=0.3; //increase angle for next rotation
trace("hit2"); //to check if the function ends
}

magnet1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_magnet); //for start dragging //object "magnet"
magnet1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_magnet); //for stop dragging //object "magnet"


function start_magnet(event:MouseEvent):void{

    magnet1.startDrag(); //start dragging of object "magnet"

    //check if the two objects are close enough
    if(magnet1.x >pendulum1.x && (magnet1.x-pendulum1.x)<100){
        trace("range detect");
    //check if it is the first time which the two objects are close enough
    if(moved_once==0){
        trace("called move");
        move_pendulum(event); //call function for rotating object "rotation"
        moved_once++; //increase counter for not rotating again
            }                                       
                                                            }

                                            }//end of function                                                  

function stop_magnet(event:MouseEvent):void{

    magnet1.stopDrag(); //stop dragging of object
    trace("stopped");
    }
```

I got no error or anything else.What is going wrong? I can't see anything.

Comment: Saying the code stopped working properly is a bit vague. What is happening ? Are you getting traces ? If you aren't getting the "range detect" trace, you should be starting there. Right ?

Comment: @prototypical Yes, thank you. I added this info in the description.I got all traces, but i got no move as it did before.

Comment: no move of what ? the magnet or the pendulum ?? Based on your code, the pendulum will stop moving at all if that condition is EVER true and won't start moving again. The move_pendulum function is where the angle is being incremented.

Comment: no move of pendulum. what i want is to move the pendulum once the magnet is close to the pendulum

Comment: If there are other types of movement for the pendulum that are no longer happening, this code and your description doesn't specify that.

Comment: When you say "move the pendulum" , do you mean rotate it ?

Comment: there is no other code. i just want to rotate the pendulum when the magnet is close

Comment: trace your angle value, is it changing ? is it possible that it's being modified elsewhere ? If you are getting that trace every frame, then it should be rotating - so long as angle is actually incrementing as you 'expect'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41803/discussion-between-dchris-and-prototypical)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
if(moved_once==0){
move_pendulum(event); //call function for rotating object "rotation"
moved_once++; //increase counter for not rotating again
}
```

You are checking the value of the global var moved_once, if its 0 then you move the pendulum and then increment moved_once. After this point moved_once = 1 and the condition (moved_once == 0) is never again true.
Add to the fact that the one and only time that you call move_pendulum angle = 0 (and sin(0) = 0 and 0 * rotate = 0) it's not going anywhere.
If you always want the pendulum to move then remove the if entirely. If you only want the pendulum to move if, for example, you are dragging the magnet then you'd be better replacing moved_once with a bool anyway.